# Is there an established way to create a 2D XY NavMesh in Unity?

Tags: unity, 2d, ai, path-finding, navmesh

Specifically, one in the empty space between colliders, rather than on an XZ plane (more or less) over the surface of a collider?

Specifically this is because I have a drone, in a current project, which must follow a target. This target isn't always reachable by shortest-path, and I'm currently experimenting with a number of algorithms to find a way to guide it around obstacles. I am on something of a deadline and would like to minimize my work, if I can.

I recognize that there are cheats around this, like having it magically appear from off-screen at a critical distance. I'm going to implement them in any case, but that's not what this question is about.

Unity's NavMesh tools were initially alluring, but as far as I can tell they seem to require a very specific FPS-like setup for this project, which I am in no way following. This feels unlike Unity Technologies, and particularly short-sighted of them; so before I go further, I would like to verify that I'm interpreting all of this correctly.

For the sake of stability, I would like to avoid hack-around solutions, if possible. All the same, they are welcome.